# mod_proxy vs mod_jk and .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

Does the mod_jk module reads .htaccess, i know mod_proxy dont if you did something like this

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9080/
```

since you will be passing everything to the tomcat container. Will doing the same with JkMount work, e.g.

```
JkMount /ajp13
JkMount /* ajp13
```

Does it parse only jsp(even if i didnt specify explicilty) and leave the rest to apache, i would like to know how it internally work.

Answer (score 0):

No; proxied requests aren't mapped to filesystem locations, so the `DocumentRoot` and any `.htaccess` files in it don't apply.

The directives in your `.htaccess` should be placed in a `<Location>` block instead.

Comment: what about JKMount, how does it internally work, i know it lets apache handles the .htaccess